# Building a capacitor, and the ESR is high. What can I do to reduce it?

Tags: capacitor, frequency, resonant

I have an LC circuit, with an inductor of [1 mH](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/SRR1260-102K/1969978), and a capacitor of around 1 nF. I built a capacitor using two aluminum plates and a [dielectric material](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0759SV64G) that I got from Amazon. When at resonance 144Khz or in phase, the ESR of the capacitor is around 25 ohms. What can I do to reduce the ESR of the capacitor?  Do I change the dielectric material?

When Vin and Vout are in phase, I measured the signal OF Vin and Vout, and used a voltage divider with 25 ohm to determine the ESR. To be more specfic, we can represent R1 as LC @ Resonant and R2 as 25Ohms. So we can use votlage divider to determine the ESR.

[image]

Comment: That sounds more like the DCR of L . How did you measure this? Where are the specs?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I have added spec and extra info.

Comment: No specs for L are shown. This is not how you specify DCR or ESR or measure each in L, C

Comment: 144khz sounds like a Tesla Coil.  What voltages is this cap subjected to?  In general, sounds like you need to increase the plate-wire conductivity or decrease the void space between plates / dielectric.  A vacuum pump could help remove air, but for big plates this means a large mechanical force.  PVC (plus adhesive!) has a relatively low [permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) ([more](https://electronicsreference.com/references/relative-permittivity/)).  The cap could be made smaller if a higher-permittivity dielectric is used.

Comment: Until you define specs for your desired Cap in terms breakdown voltage or BDV, ESR, Rp , Rs or SRF, & C, I must DV -1 your question and will upvote after you do this,

Answer (score 1):

Proof by demonstration why you cannot resolve DCR of L from ESR of C  **to simply compare with a Resistor current.** You must use an RLC bridge to match the component or a constant current source and measure V and phase like a digital RLC meter or some other method.  The loop resistance adds and is not separated/resolved as you did it.
[image]

The same issue occurs in parallel mode.

[image]

[How to calculate the gain of a RLC tank filter?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369378/how-to-calculate-the-gain-of-a-rlc-tank-filter)

1nF caps are usually 1m to 10m range.  1mH chokes are usually 1 to 10 Ohms  (but tiny ones can be much higher, and huge ones much lower)

The impedance your LC is 1k at resonance and Q factor thus depends on Series ESR+DCR , thus 1k/25 = 40 when 100 is easily done with a better L.  The ESR of your Cap depends on electrode=dielectric interface and thus with possible voids and smooth surface, you may have something else.  Try using a better L and define your current limits a driver impedance along with your test methods.  Refer to my above answer for easy calculation graphically from the intersection or RLCf.   Refer to any OEM disti such as dK for better L's loss rated by current and temperature rise.  [Sample](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Wheatstone_bridge)

If your coil is very low DCR and you still have high ESR in the cap consider that Cap design often includes increasing the electrode area by roughness using an etching process and all air voids are eliminated.  Thus you may not have the ideal design for  your application.

You may want to step back and define your overall objective in terms of RLCf, current, voltage , Q gain and application process in a list in your question.

### added

The methods to measure your characteristics in your circuit vary widely from;

- Finite element analysis using Ansys, ADS or COMSOL Physics
- Quasistatic reduction of Maxwell  equations into Darwin equations,
- Use an RLC meter at different frequencies near or around your operating f to estimate the RsRpLsCp parameters
- use a discrete equivalent circuit to match exactly the swept frequency response for some fixed attenuation - 6dB or 50% flat response or some small ratio.  (otherwise known as the [Bridge Method](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bridge_circuit))

  - There are many models and posthumous names for each type of bridge and DC models; [Wheatstone](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Wheatstone_bridge), Kelvin, Thomson etc.
  - There are also many for AC bridges for testing L and C independently
  - You can also measure each complex parameter if you can model it and match the spectral response uniquely.

### Recommend

- use a good RLC meter at 100 kHz.
- imagine each R on the left is some RsRpLC circuit and when the impedance is matched above or below by some attenuation ratio over all spectrum of concern, then the right side R ratio can be used to match the left and thus each element of RLC (f) of any complexity can be matched.

[image]

If you exclude the inductor, one can measure the ESR using a reference R near the estimated value of ESR and expect -6dB drop if equal for f>> f-3dB

[image]

[Follow my simulation and compare plots](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%202660151653.524913%0Ac%20800%20384%20800%20336%200%201e-9%200%0Al%20720%20416%20720%20464%200%200.001%200%0Aw%20832%20336%20880%20336%200%0Aw%20880%20336%20928%20336%200%0Ar%20720%20464%20720%20496%200%201.5%0A170%20880%20336%20880%20304%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AO%20880%20448%20912%20448%200%0AB%201184%20144%201312%20448%203%20Box%0Aw%20800%20336%20832%20336%200%0Aw%20800%20416%20832%20416%200%0Ar%20800%20416%20800%20384%200%2047%0AS%20880%20448%20880%20416%200%200%20false%200%202%0Ar%20960%20416%20960%20384%200%201.5%0Aw%20928%20416%20960%20416%200%0Aw%20928%20336%20960%20336%200%0Ar%20880%20528%20880%20448%200%201%0Ag%20880%20528%20880%20544%200%0Ar%201056%20464%201056%20496%200%2047%0Al%201056%20416%201056%20464%200%200.001%200%0Ac%20960%20384%20960%20336%200%201e-9%200%0Aw%20832%20416%20864%20416%200%0Aw%20928%20416%20896%20416%200%0A) by clicking SPDT switch (careful not to move it). Add or change anything you like.

Comment: I am using a 1mH that has a DCR of 1.7 Ohms max, and built a capacitor. Sine we know Vin and Vout, would it not make sense to do voltage divider with R1 representing LC at resonance and R2 represent the 25 Ohms.  We can determine R1 which represent ESR?

Comment: @Sam No It would not as DCR and ESR are not resolved.  Would you prefer an answer if I used Coulomb’s , Biot-Savart’s , Gauss's  or all of Maxwell's Laws.. Eddy current losses occur in conductors modeled as increased resistance opposing the AC reduced skin depth and thus conductor thickness. This is insignificant for the C.

Answer (score 1):

The inductor is likely the culprit.
First, you need to determine the real loss of the inductor using the technique you are currently using. Use a commercial 1 nF capacitor, preferably NPO or X7R dielectric (X7R is very common) as these parts will have minimal loss resistance. This removes your bespoke capacitor from the equation which is of unknown quality.

When you test with your bespoke capacitor, you can subtract the inductor loss resistance from the total loss measurement to get the loss from the bespoke capacitor.

A bit of background regarding inductors ...
There are few loss factors you need to consider, DC loss, AC loss, core loss.

**DC loss** is just that. Measure with your ohm meter.

**AC winding loss** is due to eddy current losses. **Skin** effect is widely bantered, but under 1 MHz it is usually insignificant compared to **proximity** effect losses. Proximity effect loss shows up as a real resistance and can be very significant depending on wire diameter (there is an optimal size for a given frequency) and frequency. It is counterintuitive - as the wire diameter increases, the AC losses increase. Having such a low DC resistance for a 1 mH inductor says that the wire diameter is fairly large as far as proximity effect is concerned. A common way to reduce eddy current losses is using Litz wire. Bunched conductors are just as effective in reducing proximity effect losses, but not as effective for skin effect losses.

**Core loss** is due to the loss physics of the core. If air core, no appreciable loss. If ferrite, or some other material, core loss is dependent on frequency, flux density, and core volume. At low voltages, the core loss probably is insignificant compared to winding losses.

[Edit]
As an example of winding loss, the series inductance and loss resistance was measured for a similar type of 47uH coupled inductor on a HP4194A impedance analyzer. Above 20kHz, the loss resistance (appears as a real resistance) starts to increase due to proximity effect. The inductance is quite a bit lower than your 1mH inductor, however, it does show that the real loss at higher frequencies is much higher than the DC resistance of 0.17 ohms.

[image]

Comment: If Q is reasonably high (40) and SRF > 1 MHz as all the sample chokes in Digikey.  L is OK. The problem is not Inductor Eddy Current loss increasing DCR , rather that would shunt L with Rp.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 His problem is most likely AC loss resistance (a real loss, as opposed to reactive) at 150 kHz. The DCR is added to the real AC loss resistance (increases as frequency increases) at the measurement frequency. I have added measurement data from an actual part at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Yes, the measurements must be done independently for L and C to capture  the swept impedance response or V/phase response to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are several ways to measure Q or ESR, which won't all give the same result, namely depending on whether the 25R sense resistor is included.  The calculation must be matched to the circuit being tested.

An example circuit, with automated calculations, can be found at my website here:
[LC Resonance | Calculators | Seven Transistor Labs, LLC](https://seventransistorlabs.com/Calc/RLC.html#rlc)
I would recommend the "by resistor divider" or "frequency and Q factor" method.

Note that the latter gives parallel loss equivalent; this can be converted to ESR by dividing by Q^2.

Regarding the dielectric: vinyl is a terrible choice, having quite high losses.  Polyethylene and polypropylene are the best readily available films, with polyester (Mylar, etc.) being a second best option.  This is probably not the dominant loss in your case*, but something you will quickly find problematic if this is for a power/resonant application.  (Indeed, vinyl sheet is typically welded with high-frequency dielectric heating machines.)

*Inductor typ. Q = 30 at 252kHz (it will be slightly lower at 144kHz).  1mH at 144kHz is 904 ohms reactance, dividing by Q = 30 gives 30 ohms ESR.